# Fastlane Match - different branches of Project need to use different Apple Dev Accounts

Tags: git, fastlane, fastlane-match, fastlane-gym

I am just new to fastlane and have been tasked with deploying an application that is far from the norm.

We have a Master branch and off of that branch we have several release/ branches. Each of these release/ branches is a different setup for specific clients. Our initial setup had us using fastlane and match from the one apple developer account - which was fine.

However Apple have now required each of the separate setups/apps for clients to be under their own developer accounts. Thus we are now in a position where we have one project but will be required to run different fastlane and match setups from different branches.

Is this possible from the same project? Do we need a match repo for each branch? Or are we going to be able to use fastlane at all for this setup?

Answer (score 0):

Use one branch per team, as described here:
[https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/#important-use-one-git-branch-per-team)

Answer (score 0):

Fastlane match now supports storing the profiles and certificates to google cloud or amazon s3 storage. You are no longer required to store it in a git repo and be restricted by the branching convention.

See more info below:

[Fastlane match google cloud storage](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/#google-cloud-storage)

[Fastlane match Amazon s3](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/#amazon-s3)